# how to move to new line in textbox after second comma in python

Tags: python-3.x, text, barcode-scanner

I am new here and I am complete dumb and struggling with python. I hope I can get a little help here.

I got a script for importing some things into database. The script is working very well, but I want to improve the working process. We are scanning serial numbers and "ID" (with barcode scanner) in one textbox field.

The process is: One scan, then I need to enter comma. Second scan enter for new line.

In the new line: One scan, then I need to enter comma. Second scan enter for new line, etc.

I managed with suffix on scanner that the scanner automatically after scan enter the comma.

ex. serial, id,

What I need is that the script after second scan deletes the comma and goes to new line. After that the scan process goes from beginning.

**The final output should look like:**

- serial1,id1
- serial2,id2
- serial3,id3

etc.

I tried with

```
re.sub('(,[^,]*),', r'\1 \n', line)
```

But I don't know if I need a loop here because a new line or I can take the last line and work only on last line. Is here necessary to join the text. Thanks in advance for any kind of help or suggestions.

**Edit:**
I don't have much of code, the code what I have is not relevant for that what I need. The only code what i have is this. A web text field where i need to format the data as described (preparing for import)

```
serialnumbermac = TextVar(
        description="Serial number, MAC - with comma.",
        re.sub('(,[^,]*),', r'\1 \n', line),
        required=True
    )
```

Comment: Formatting and grammatical errors causes ambiguity.

Comment: english is not my native language.

Comment: You need to show us the current code, your inputs and current vs expected outputs or any errors you might get, in the form of a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)